# SQL CREATE A TABLE FROM ANOTHER TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following question because have no idea how to solve this:

I have the following table

```
Column
------
04/2013
07/2013
12/2013
07/2014
12/2014
07/2015
12/2015
07/2016
12/2016
07/2017
12/2017
07/2018
12/2018
07/2019
12/2019
07/2020
08/2020
```

and I would like to get another table from this one, that contains "periods" like this:

```
Start  End
04/2013 06/2013
07/2013 11/2013
12/2013 06/2014
07/2014 11/2014
12/2014 06/2015
07/2015 11/2015
12/2015 06/2016
07/2016 11/2016
12/2016 06/2017
07/2017 11/2017
12/2017 06/2018
07/2018 11/2018
12/2018 06/2019
07/2019 11/2019
12/2019 06/2020
07/2020 08/2020
```

where the firs row of the source table is the begining of the periods, and the last row of the source table is the end of the periods, and the second column of the second desired table is decreasing a month of the start date of the following row in the source table.

I don't want to use any cursor or similar, just asking if there is any way to do it sing sql query.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, what is the data type of the column.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Yes, you right, sorry. SQL SERVER 2008 R2, so I think LEAD function does not work here.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `LEAD()`.  The trick is then modifying the date to subtract one month.  I am assuming that the column is actually a date.

In standard SQL, this would look like:

```
select col,
       lead(col) over (order by col) - interval '1 month'
from t;
```

Note that this includes the last row with a `NULL` value for the second column.  That seems like a feature to me, but you can use the above as a subquery and filter out the `NULL` value.

EDIT:

In unsupported versions of SQL Server, you can use a lateral join or subquery:

```
select col,
       (select dateadd(month, 1, min(col)) 
        from t t2
        where t2.col > t.col
       ) 
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. It'd work but I work with SQL SERVER 2008 R2 TT. But thanks a lot.

Comment: @bentakayze . . . (1) Your question is tagged "sql" with no database.  This is a **standard** SQL answer.  (2) Why would you be using a commercial product that is no longer being supported?  Upgrade to a *supported* product.  And tag your questions with the database you are using.

Comment: Gordon... (1), I know. (2) I am not reponsible for that. (3) Have a tea and keep calm.

Answer (score 0):

To perform date arithmetics, you should convert the year-month literal to a 1st-of-month date literal, as I do below. I also give you the choice to differ from the successor by month or by day. And the choice to have strings or DATE types in your target table.

```
CREATE TABLE output AS
WITH 
-- your input
input (col) AS (
          SELECT '04/2013'
UNION ALL SELECT '07/2013'
UNION ALL SELECT '12/2013'
UNION ALL SELECT '07/2014'
UNION ALL SELECT '12/2014'
UNION ALL SELECT '07/2015'
UNION ALL SELECT '12/2015'
UNION ALL SELECT '07/2016'
UNION ALL SELECT '12/2016'
UNION ALL SELECT '07/2017'
UNION ALL SELECT '12/2017'
UNION ALL SELECT '07/2018'
UNION ALL SELECT '12/2018'
UNION ALL SELECT '07/2019'
UNION ALL SELECT '12/2019'
UNION ALL SELECT '07/2020'
UNION ALL SELECT '08/2020'
)
,
-- need to convert to DATE type to sort properly
todate AS (
  SELECT
    col
  , TO_DATE(col,'MM/YYYY') AS dt
  FROM input
)
-- remove the cols you don't need, but it will 
-- be handy to have them all as DATES
-- I'll also add a more convenient col, ony 1 day before the next
,
one_row_too_many AS (
  SELECT
    col                                                           AS start_string
  , dt                                                            AS start_dt
  , LEAD(dt) OVER(ORDER BY dt) - 1                                AS end_dt_by_day
  , TO_CHAR(LEAD(dt) OVER(ORDER BY dt) - 1,'MM/YYYY')             AS end_string_by_day
  , CAST(LEAD(dt) OVER(ORDER BY dt) - INTERVAL '1 MONTH' AS DATE) AS end_dt_by_month
  FROM todate
)
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
one_row_too_many
WHERE end_dt_by_day IS NOT NULL;

-- CONTROL QUERY
SELECT * FROM output;
-- out Time: First fetch (0 rows): 51.357 ms. All rows formatted: 51.364 ms
-- out  start_string |  start_dt  | end_dt_by_day | end_string_by_day | end_dt_by_month 
-- out --------------+------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------
-- out  04/2013      | 2013-04-01 | 2013-06-30    | 06/2013           | 2013-06-01
-- out  07/2013      | 2013-07-01 | 2013-11-30    | 11/2013           | 2013-11-01
-- out  07/2014      | 2014-07-01 | 2014-11-30    | 11/2014           | 2014-11-01
-- out  07/2015      | 2015-07-01 | 2015-11-30    | 11/2015           | 2015-11-01
-- out  07/2016      | 2016-07-01 | 2016-11-30    | 11/2016           | 2016-11-01
-- out  07/2017      | 2017-07-01 | 2017-11-30    | 11/2017           | 2017-11-01
-- out  07/2018      | 2018-07-01 | 2018-11-30    | 11/2018           | 2018-11-01
-- out  07/2019      | 2019-07-01 | 2019-11-30    | 11/2019           | 2019-11-01
-- out  07/2020      | 2020-07-01 | 2020-07-31    | 07/2020           | 2020-07-02
-- out  12/2013      | 2013-12-01 | 2014-06-30    | 06/2014           | 2014-06-01
-- out  12/2014      | 2014-12-01 | 2015-06-30    | 06/2015           | 2015-06-01
-- out  12/2015      | 2015-12-01 | 2016-06-30    | 06/2016           | 2016-06-01
-- out  12/2016      | 2016-12-01 | 2017-06-30    | 06/2017           | 2017-06-01
-- out  12/2017      | 2017-12-01 | 2018-06-30    | 06/2018           | 2018-06-01
-- out  12/2018      | 2018-12-01 | 2019-06-30    | 06/2019           | 2019-06-01
-- out  12/2019      | 2019-12-01 | 2020-06-30    | 06/2020           | 2020-06-01
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. It'd work but I work with SQL SERVER 2008 R2 TT. But thanks a lot.

Comment: I have fix it using self joins: SELECT T.fefecto 
     , TPrev.fefecto 
  FROM #Temp AS T LEFT JOIN #Temp AS TPrev ON TPrev.fefecto = (SELECT Top 1 (T2.fefecto)
                                                             FROM #Temp T2
                                                            WHERE cast('01/' + T2.fefecto as DATE) > cast('01/' + T.fefecto as date ))
ORDER BY cast('01/' + T.fefecto as DATE)